# Making an arduino alternate functions

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to write a bit of c code for an arduino, to alternate between two different functions by using a switching variable. Could anyone help me make this work?

```
int hold = 1;
void setup() {
}

void loop() {
       Serial.println(hold);
     if (hold == 1){
     hold = 2;
       }
     if (hold == 2){
     hold = 1;
       }              
}
```

Comment: That will work, but you need to use `else if`, otherwise, you set `hold` to 2, then the next `if` will fire and set it back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int hold = 1;

// ...

if (hold)
    functionA();
else
    functionB();
hold = !hold;
```

**EDIT**
Here are two more ways to do it. The first is simpler, using the `switch` statement, which is really just another way of doing `if...else..`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMFUNCS    4

int funcA(void);
int funcB(void);
int funcC(void);
int funcD(void);

int main(void){
    int action = 0;
    int res;
    while(1) {
        switch(action) {
            case 0:  res = funcA();
                     break;
            case 1:  res = funcB();
                     break;
            case 2:  res = funcC();
                     break;
            default: res = funcD();
                     break;
        }
        printf ("Function returned %d\n", res);
        action = (action + 1) % NUMFUNCS;
    }
    return 0;
}

int funcA(void) {
    return 1;
}
int funcB(void) {
    return 2;
}
int funcC(void) {
    return 3;
}
int funcD(void) {
    return 4;
}
```

A little more complex is by using an array of function pointers. If you want to pass arguments to the functions, you'll need to change the array declaration too. The drawback is that unless you have variadic functions, they must all have the same arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMFUNCS    4

int funcA(void);
int funcB(void);
int funcC(void);
int funcD(void);

int (*funcarry[NUMFUNCS])(void) = {     // array of function pointers
    funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD
};

int main(void){
    int action = 0;
    int res;
    while(1) {
        res = (*funcarry[action])();
        printf ("Function returned %d\n", res);
        action = (action + 1) % NUMFUNCS;
    }
    return 0;
}

int funcA(void) {
    return 1;
}
int funcB(void) {
    return 2;
}
int funcC(void) {
    return 3;
}
int funcD(void) {
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: I need to make it go through 4+ different things, and choose one each loop, so I don't think else is an option. Unless I am wrong that is.

Comment: @Warior4356 I have extended my answer.